# what Debian package provides Java_JAR_EXECUTABLE and Java_JAVADOC_EXECUTABLE requested by FindJava.cmake?

Tags: java, cmake, debian

The C++ static analyser https://github.com/animatedb/oovaide is written in Java. Attempting to build it from source, I encounter the following basic Java configuration problem:

CMake reports

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find Java (missing: Java_JAR_EXECUTABLE Java_JAVADOC_EXECUTABLE)
  (found version "11")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindJava.cmake:332 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  oovJavaParser/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)
```

Which Debian package provides these dependencies?

I installed `openjdk-11-jre`, which provides `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`, which can be called as `/usr/bin/java` thanks to `/etc/alternatives`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides `openjdk-11-jre`, also `openjdk-11-jdk` is needed.

Upon which `CMake` came up with the next error:

`Could NOT find JNI (missing: JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY
   JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH)`

Which could be solved with `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64`, as suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/19202688/1017348.